# Cisco Website - Unable to login

Tags: cisco

Am I the only one having issues with the Cisco website? I am trying to download firmware for the NSS4000 and can't get logged in. I have created like three accounts and they all seem to work but won't allow a login. Upon attempting a password reset the site just times out. Am I crazy?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to log in with no real issue.  Also this isn't really a question that should be on server fault as it doesn't directly involve server or network administration.  Might want to give Cisco a call though if you're still running into issues.

Comment: I think it is related to the account creation. I am trying to download firmware for a network storage device... thought that qualified. Anyways thanks for the info - I will have to track down one of my colleagues with an account.